# This is a hill cipher im getting an error

Tags: java

This is for a hill cipher program that I am coding for my class. I am getting an error message that tell me that state .class is excpeted. The error occurs on line 51. If you can help that would be great and explain why I am getting this error in the first place.

inv_temp[i][j] = determinant(temp,order-1)/float(res);

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class main{
    public static int n = 3;
    double determinant(double[][] array,int order){

        if (order == 1)
            return array[0][0];
        if (order == 2)
            return (array[0][0]*array[1][1] - array[0][1]*array[1][0]);
        double answer = 0;
        double[][] temp = new double[n][n];
        for (int i = 0; i < order; i++){
            for (int j = 1; j < order; j++){
                int t = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < order; k++){
                    if (k == i){
                        t++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    else{
                        temp[j-1][k-t] = array[j][k];
                    }
                }
            }
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                answer += array[0][i]*determinant(temp,order-1);
            else
                answer -= array[0][i]*determinant(temp,order-1);
        }
        return answer;
    }

    public static double[][] inverse(double[][] inv,double[][] array,int order){
        double res = determinant(array,order);
        double[][] inv_temp = new double[n][n];
        if (res != 0){
            double[][] temp = new double[n][n];
            for (int i = 0; i < order; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < order; j++){
                    int t = 0;
                    for (int k = 0; k < order; k++){
                        if (k == i){
                            t++;
                            continue;
                        }
                        int tt = 0;
                        for (int l = 0; l < order; l++){
                            if (l == j){
                                tt++;
                                continue;
                            }
                            temp[k-t][l-tt] = array[k][l];
                        }
                    }
                    if (i % 2 == 0){
                        if (j % 2 == 0){
                            inv_temp[i][j] = determinant(temp,order-1)/float(res);    
                        }
                        else{
                            inv_temp[i][j] = -1*(determinant(temp,order-1))/res;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        if (j % 2 == 0){
                            inv_temp[i][j] = -1*(determinant(temp,order-1))/res;      
                        }
                        else{
                            inv_temp[i][j] = (determinant(temp,order-1))/res;     
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < order; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < order; j++){
                    inv[j][i] = inv_temp[i][j] % 26;
                }
            }
            return inv;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `float(res)` should do/represent?

Comment: `float` is one of Java's [reserved keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html). If that was supposed to be name of method then you need to rename it. If that was supposed to be casting then you misplaced your parenthesis.